# How can I upload a file using Catalyst?

Tags: perl, file-upload, catalyst

I am working on an internal web based application for storing and cataloging photos. How should I retrieve, and save these files to the server?

*Note: I want to save the files to the file system, not to a database.*
*Similar to [How can I handle HTTP file uploads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162677/how-can-i-handle-http-file-uploads)*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Start with your familiar upload INPUT on your HTML form and ensure that the HTML form tag has the parameter `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Your [Catalyst::Request](http://p3rl.org/Catalyst::Request) object (`$c->request`) provides two methods for accessing and manipulating the files.

Each file upload field will be instantiated as a [Catalyst::Request::Upload](http://p3rl.org/Catalyst::Request::Upload) object.

`$c->request->upload` will return the Upload objects in scalar or list form.
`$c->request->uploads` will return a reference to hash of Upload objects.

The Upload object provides several method for saving and copying the files.

Check out the man pages that I've linked above.

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst::Request
http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst::Request::Upload

Comment: is $c->request->uploads really returning a reference to a hash? When I look at the output in dumper it seems to be returning an array reference

Comment: @MatthewLock - either the docs are wrong, or you're misusing/misreading your dumper.  The docs still say hashref.

Comment: Yes uploads is returning a hashref if there's a single upload, but an arrayref or hashrefs if there are multiple uploads.